# Using linked series in one chart has bug in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use multiple series in one chart and linking the series. 
Here is one example of JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tRZz5/1/

```
{
            name: 'Red',
            id: 'red',
            data: [{
                x: 1392140700000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392140760000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392140820000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392141000000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392141060000,
                y: 2
            }],
            color: 'red',
            lineWidth: 20
        },
        {
            name: 'Green',
            id: 'green',
            data: [{
                x: 1392140880000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392140940000,
                y: 2
            }],
            color: 'green',
            linkedTo: 'red',
            lineWidth: 20
        },
        {
            name: 'Grey',
            id: 'Grey',
            data: [{
                x: 1392140820000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392140880000,
                y: 2
            }],
            color: 'grey',
            linkedTo: 'red',
            lineWidth: 20
        }
```

This works totally fine.

But in the same code when I move Red series to the end while adding into array then it behaves differently and put total red color even if I have specified different color in between.
http://jsfiddle.net/tRZz5/2/

```
{
            name: 'Green',
            id: 'green',
            data: [{
                x: 1392140880000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392140940000,
                y: 2
            }],
            color: 'green',
            linkedTo: 'red',
            lineWidth: 20
        },
        {
            name: 'Grey',
            id: 'Grey',
            data: [{
                x: 1392140820000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392140880000,
                y: 2
            }],
            color: 'grey',
            linkedTo: 'red',
            lineWidth: 20
        },
        {
            name: 'Red',
            id: 'red',
            data: [{
                x: 1392140700000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392140760000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392140820000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392141000000,
                y: 2
            },
                  {
                x: 1392141060000,
                y: 2
            }],
            color: 'red',
            lineWidth: 20
        }
```

Here I just move red series from top to bottom nothing else and series is being painted totally red, I think it should same as previous series.

Comment: No bug here. All your data is the same, you put the red series last, it's drawn last **on top** of the other series.  Here's with some `zIndexs` to change the draw order: http://jsfiddle.net/tRZz5/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot got the way it is painting on the top.